# How to join two model and display them in view in mvc 3.0 EF 5

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have two tables which have primary and foriegn key concept. I want to get the combined data on behalf of those keys. i don't know how to bind both the table into single model and display it into view.

**Model**

```
public class TVSerialModel
{
    public Int32 Serial_ID { get; set; } // primary key
    public string Serial_Name { get; set; }                 
    public int? Release_Year { get; set; }           
}

public class TVSerialEpisodeModel
{
    public Int64 Video_ID { get; set; } 
    public Int32 Serial_ID { get; set; }// foriegn key
    public string Episode_Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }        
    public DateTime Uploaded_Time { get; set; }
}

public class TVSerial_Episode_VM
{
    public IEnumerable<TVSerialEpisodeModel> tvserialEpisode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TVSerialModel> Tvserial { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult NewEpisodeReleased()
{
    cDBContext tvContext = new cDBContext();

    TVSerial_Episode_VM tves=new TVSerial_Episode_VM(); 
    tves= tvContext.dbTvSerialEpisodes.
    Join(tvContext.dbTvSerials, p => p.Serial_ID, r => r.Serial_ID,(p, r) => new { p, r }).
Select(o => new TVSerial_Episode_VM
            { ****what should i write here to get all columns from both table**** }).
Take(9).ToList();            
    return View(tves);
}
```

**Expected Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If TVSerialEpisode has a property `TVSerial`, you can just dot through your foreign keys.

```
cDBContext.dbTvSerialEpisode
    .Select(t => 
        new {
            t.TVSerial.Serial_ID, 
            t.TVSerial.Serial_Name, 
            t.Episode_Name
        })
    .Take(9)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to improve little bit the models you used with EF. You must include the reference object in model.

Like this

```
public virtual TVSerialModel TVSerialModel { get; set; }
```

in main table. This way you can select referred table too.

Comment: Entity Framework uses lazy loading when you have defined your relationships with the virtual keyword. This means, the related objects will not be loaded until they're first accessed.

Lazy loading sounds good, but it can slow down performance because there are more round trips to the database, and lazy loading can cause select N+1 issues if you’re not careful. You can prevent lazy loading and select N+1 issues by turning off lazy loading.

https://www.talksharp.com/increase-enity-framework-performance

Answer (score 0):

[EF Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb738708%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public ActionResult NewEpisodeReleased()
{
    cDBContext tvContext = new cDBContext();

    TVSerial_Episode_VM tves=new TVSerial_Episode_VM(); 
    tves= tvContext.dbTvSerialEpisodes.Include("TVSerialEpisodeModel")
                       .Include("TVSerialModel").ToList();            
    return View(tves);
}
```